# Load Dojo from CDN using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dojo, cdn

Here is the example that I took from the [article](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dojo_config/) and a bit changed. This example perfectly works

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojoConfig = {
                parseOnLoad: false,
                async: true
            };
        </script>   
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /// Require the registry, parser, Dialog, and wait for domReady
            require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/parser", "dojo/json", "dojo/_base/config", "dijit/Dialog"], function (registry, parser, JSON, config) {
                // Explicitly parse the page
                parser.parse();
                // Find the dialog
                var dialog = registry.byId("dialog");
                // Set the content equal to what dojo.config is
                dialog.set("content", "<b>it works!</b>");
                // Show the dialog
                dialog.show();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div id="dialog" data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

now I want to modify it and load Dojo dynamically using jQuery. Here is the example how I do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            dojoConfig = {
                parseOnLoad: false,
                async: true
            };

            $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js")
            .done(function (script, textStatus) {
                /// Require the registry, parser, Dialog, and wait for domReady
                require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/parser", "dojo/json", "dojo/_base/config", "dijit/Dialog"], function (registry, parser, JSON, config) {
                    // Explicitly parse the page
                    parser.parse();
                    // Find the dialog
                    var dialog = registry.byId("dialog");
                    // Set the content equal to what dojo.config is
                    dialog.set("content", "<b>it works!</b>");
                    // Show the dialog
                    dialog.show();
                });
            })
            .fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                alert('Cannot load Dojo.js');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="dialog" data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but looks like I do something wrong cause it raises the next error

```
NotFoundError: Node was not found
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
Line 2
```

I suspect that Dojo is not ready yet but maybe I'm wrong... Is it possible to use jQuery to load Dojo dynamically at all?

Comment: Raises *what* error? Please include relevant details in your questions.

Comment: just updated the text...

Comment: Just noticed the other question you posted a few days ago (after placing my answer).  If you need both Dojo & jQuery and need to use a CDN, then I suggest you load both in your head.  The dojo 1.8 loader is minimal (esp. when using the bulit versions), so the overhead is small.  Extra modules are only loaded when you chose to load them or parse some content.  You could also load a local version of the dojo loader but load modules from the CDN by setting appropriate values for dojo, dojox and dijit (this ought to work as it is the loader that is breaking things).

Comment: That's right. Actually I have to load jQuery and Dojo from CDN (not from my local server) and the reason for that the jQuery widgets library should be loaded on different sites on different domains, so it doesn't matter where I load it from... from Google or from my local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally looks like I found the reliable solution that based on the [article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/)... here is the working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadScript(url, callback) {
            var script = document.createElement("script")
            script.type = "text/javascript";

            if (script.readyState) {  //IE
                script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete") {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        callback();
                    }
                };
            } else {  //Others
                script.onload = function () {
                    callback();
                };
            }

            script.src = url;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            dojoConfig = {
                parseOnLoad: false,
                async: true
            };

            loadScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js", function () {
                /// Require the registry, parser, Dialog, and wait for domReady
                require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/parser", "dojo/json", "dojo/_base/config", "dijit/Dialog"], function (registry, parser, JSON, config) {
                    // Explicitly parse the page
                    parser.parse();
                    // Find the dialog
                    var dialog = registry.byId("dialog");
                    // Set the content equal to what dojo.config is
                    dialog.set("content", "<b>it works!</b>");
                    // Show the dialog
                    dialog.show();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="dialog" data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not pure jQuery solution but it's better for me then include Dojo script on the page...

Answer (score 1):

The "Node was not found" error is caused by the loader trying to locate the script tag that loaded it.  This is a *trick* that Dojo uses when it is loaded from a CDN (like the Google one you have used) to try to find the url path for loading modules.

The jQuery $.getScript() function is not actually injecting a script tag into the page but rather loading via XHR and then evaling the code.  Hence, the tag that Dojo is looking for cannot be found.  This only happens when using a CDN.  If you used your own local copy of Dojo rather than a CDN, it can be made to work.

I'm not sure that loading Dojo via jQuery is good practice.  It is probably better to load both of them separately or to do it the other way round (ie. load jQuery inside of Dojo).  I assume that you require the functionality of both or you wouldn't be trying this.

To load jQuery as Dojo module you could alter your code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
        media="screen"
    />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
            "parseOnLoad": false,
            "async": true,
                "packages": [{
                    "name": "jquery",
                    "location": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0",
                    "main": "jquery.min"
                }]
        };
    </script>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        define.amd.jQuery = true;  // jQuery will be loaded as an AMD module

        require([
            "jquery",
        ], function($){
            // NB: $ is only available within the scope it has been loaded
            // as it is loading as an AMD module.  Hence, $ is not globally
            // available and must be required into any scope it is used.

            $(document).ready(function () {
                require([
                    "dijit/registry",
                    "dojo/parser",
                    "dojo/json",
                    "dojo/_base/config",
                    "dijit/Dialog"
                ], function (registry, parser, JSON, config) {
                    // Explicitly parse the page
                    parser.parse();
                    // Find the dialog
                    var dialog = registry.byId("dialog");
                    // Set the content equal to what dojo.config is
                    dialog.set("content", "<b>it works!</b>");
                    // Show the dialog
                    dialog.show();
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="dialog" data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is probably better to stick to using Dojo, rather than trying to use both.  However, the above will allow both to be used together.  Dojo, has it's own ready function ([dojo/ready](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/ready.html)) that could replace $(document).ready().  Most of the functionality of jQuery is replicated in some manor within Dojo.

Loading jQuery as a Dojo module means that it is only available inside the require callback.  Hence, $ is not placed in the global scope as is normally the case.  You will have to require it into any JavaScript you need it for.

**NB:** I changed dijit.Dialog in your code to dijit/Dialog as it will not load in version 1.8 if you use the dot formation.

Comment: No, loading jQuery from Dojo won't work for me... I have to load Dojo dynamically. The example above just demonstrate the problem that I currently have... original application based on jQuery. It's jQuery widgets library that should be used on different sites in different domains. I have to integrate just one Dojo widget into that library. and I would like to load Dojo and Dojo widget only when it's needed and not every time.